# insert in database from each line of textarea field by php

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, textarea

How i can insert in database from textarea field that each line is a table in database

means I want insert in database from each line of textarea field by php

my information like this:

```
Name | FullName | Age
```

and database table:

```
id (auto insert),
name,
fullname,
age
```

thanks

Comment: if you are satisfied with the solution provided by anyone then do not forget to mark it as answered. or else no one will bother to answer you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would suggest using a delimiter at the end of the line and then convert it into an array using explode(), here is what you could do.

```
//Make sure your text have (,) comma at the end of every line
$text = 'My Name,
         My Full Name, 
         24';
//Convert it into an array
$text = explode(',', $text);
//fetch the value and assign it to variables then do an insert operation
//Use mysql_real_escape_string() to escape SQL injections.
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($text[0]);
$FullName = mysql_real_escape_string($text[1]);
$age = mysql_real_escape_string($text[2]);
```

and then you can create query like this.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO persons(name, fullName, age) values($name, $fullName, $age)";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the string, for example http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 1):

```
// assuming the text area value is in $_GET["text"]
$lines = explode("\n", $_GET["text"]);
foreach($lines as $line) {
    list($name, $fullName, $age) = explode(" | ", $line);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (name, fullname, age) VALUES ('$name', '$fullName', $age)");
}
```

Comment: I would avoid the query in the loop. Given knowledge of this code, anyone could very easily overload the system this runs on.

Comment: nobody cares about injections? Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198104/reference-what-is-a-perfect-code-sample-using-the-mysql-extension/6198584#6198584

Comment: of course injections matter, but this really wasn't a "what is the best option of doing this", but a more "how to split the data and get it ready to insert into the database".

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
// assuming textarea name is $_POST['data']
$_POST['data'] = 'Jane | Jane Doe | 23
    zxc
sadas
 John | John Doe | 48
';

// Set and trim data 
$data = (array_key_exists('data', $_POST)) ? trim($_POST['data']) : '';

if ($data !== '') {
    $lines = explode("\n", $data);
    $sql = 'insert into table (name, fullname, age) values ';
    $sql_parts = array();

    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $sql_part = array(
            'name' => null,
            'full_name' => null,
            'age' => null,
        );

        // If no divider found, skip this line
        if (strpos($line, ' | ') === false)
        {
            continue;
        }
        list($sql_part['name'], $sql_part['full_name'], $sql_part['age']) = explode(' | ', $line);

        // For the sake of this example
        // i will assume all fields are required
        // so let's check for that:
        foreach ($sql_part as $key => $item) {
            // Trim and sanitize the data:
            $item = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($item));

            // If any item is empty continue to the next line of data
            if ($item === '') {
                continue 2;
            }
            $sql_part[$key] = "'".$item."'";
        }
        $sql_parts[] = '('.implode(',', $sql_part).')';
    }

    if (empty($sql_parts) === false) {
        $sql .= implode(',', $sql_parts);
        mysql_query($sql);
    }
}
```