# multi like mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i want to getting multi query from mysql

sample :

```
<?php require_once('Connections/dbRoosary.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$maxRows_Recordset1 = 20;
$pageNum_Recordset1 = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_Recordset1'])) {
  $pageNum_Recordset1 = $_GET['pageNum_Recordset1'];
}
$startRow_Recordset1 = $pageNum_Recordset1 * $maxRows_Recordset1;

mysql_select_db($database_dbRoosary, $dbRoosary);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM product_info ORDER BY id ASC";
$query_limit_Recordset1 = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_Recordset1, $startRow_Recordset1, $maxRows_Recordset1);
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_limit_Recordset1, $dbRoosary) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_Recordset1'])) {
  $totalRows_Recordset1 = $_GET['totalRows_Recordset1'];
} else {
  $all_Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1);
  $totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($all_Recordset1);
}
$totalPages_Recordset1 = ceil($totalRows_Recordset1/$maxRows_Recordset1)-1;$maxRows_Recordset1 = 20;
$pageNum_Recordset1 = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_Recordset1'])) {
  $pageNum_Recordset1 = $_GET['pageNum_Recordset1'];
}
$startRow_Recordset1 = $pageNum_Recordset1 * $maxRows_Recordset1;

$colname_Recordset1 = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['tag'])) {
  $colname_Recordset1 = $_GET['tag'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_dbRoosary, $dbRoosary);
$query_Recordset1 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM product_info WHERE tags LIKE %s ORDER BY id ASC", GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_Recordset1 . "%", "text"));
$query_limit_Recordset1 = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_Recordset1, $startRow_Recordset1, $maxRows_Recordset1);
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_limit_Recordset1, $dbRoosary) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_Recordset1'])) {
  $totalRows_Recordset1 = $_GET['totalRows_Recordset1'];
} else {
  $all_Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1);
  $totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($all_Recordset1);
}
$totalPages_Recordset1 = ceil($totalRows_Recordset1/$maxRows_Recordset1)-1;
?>

 <?php do { ?>
HTMLs ... Element
          <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
<?php
mysql_free_result($Recordset1);
?>
```

this code is for 1 query (tags) ,
i want getting from tags or title result

Comment: Don't forget to quote all values in query. Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198104/reference-what-is-a-perfect-code-sample-using-the-mysql-extension/6198584#6198584

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE tags LIKE ? OR title LIKE ?
```

Comment: tanX BUT after error me : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 20' at line 1

Comment: @oz_ who you are referring? I clearly wrote ? as marking the use of some prepared statment

Comment: @yes123 it's not prepared statements, it's just sprintf. There should be quotes or will be injections and sql-syntax errors.

Comment: @OZ_ well of course I agree, but then your comment was better suited under his question. (i dont' have any sprintf here )

Comment: @oz_ in prepared statement you don't need quotes and you don't need `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: @Johan repeat: it's not prepared statements and not PDO.