# Storing PHP snippets in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am storing PHP snippets in a MySQL database, I am using mysql_real_escape_string and all is well unless there is a & in the php code and then I get a MySQL error.  Is there another why I should try and store this information?

Thanks

Comment: Which MySQL error do you get?

Comment: Perhaps base64_encode would be useful.

Comment: What is the MySQL Error you are getting?

Comment: It's because values are not quoted in query, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198104/reference-what-is-a-perfect-code-sample-using-the-mysql-extension/6198584#6198584

Comment: @Andre Backlund and how will you implement full text search after that? It's just useless overhead in this case.

Comment: @OZ_ I'm assuming a snippet of PHP wouldn't need to be searchable.

Comment: @Peter : why would you do that ? And after that you put your data in a php file ?

Comment: @Andre Backlund, hah, presumptuously.

Comment: actually not an error, mysql stores everything until the &

Comment: @remi bourgarel the project consists if a website with several hundred pages all of which are generated on the fly from data stored in mysql..   each of the pages now needs to be able to retrieve information from a second database (different query for each page) so that is why I want to be able to insert the php snippets.

Comment: Doh ....   it works fine if I update the db via php but not with the jquery i was using....

Thanks for your help guys

Comment: Can you show us *how* exactly you are passing this into the database?

Answer (score 3):

@Peter : unless you're building a website for helping developers, you have no reason to put php code into your database, it's a warning : this is gonna be a big nightmare to maintain/debug. Can't you link your pages to some parameters and then in your code use these parameters to build each request ? 
it may seems a simple design solution at the beginning "how god I can do whatever I want in all my pages" but it might be the worse you're taking on your poject.

I don't know how to say this but you should really try to consider an other solution. And i'm not speaing about security : if you have an SQL Injection the guy can execute SQL AND php so he can really take all your system/server down, or even attack bigger site with yours (and then you'll be responsible).

I'm really surprised everyone is fine with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [base64_encode](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) when you save snippet into the database and [base64_decode](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) when you retreive it.

Comment: Don't do it, because search in DB will be impossible.

Comment: upvoted answer. the OP wants to store code in DB, and base64 encoding is a proper solution. Also, searching the DB won't be impossible, just searching the actual code (why would that be needed anyway?)

Comment: He can store code in DB without stupid encodings! Pluses of base64 here: none; minuses: search will be disabled, overhead to encode/decode.

Comment: I just tried base64_encode but mysql still only stored up to the & is the problem maybe passing the & via post?

Comment: Doh ....   it works fine if I update the db via php but not with the jquery i was using....

Thanks for your help guys

Comment: Glad you've worked it out. You should tick Parkyprg's answer for his helping support (the tick on the left hand side of the answer)

Comment: @Ben I am not using base64_encode the problem was something else altogether

Comment: @Peter: Post your solution to the problem here as a new answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

First, I am going to go on record and say I wholeheartedly agree with remi bourgarel.  This is likely a bad idea.

But, from a technical standpoint here's how I'd do this IF I NEEDED TO:

```
$php_code = '
    <?php
        $var = "this is a string";
        $var = strtoupper($var);
        echo $var;
    ?>
';
$php_code = bin2hex($php_code);
$db->query("INSERT INTO php_code_snips (text_code) VALUES(x'{$php_code}')");
```

`bin2hex` will transform the string `$php_code` from a binary string to a hex string, and the `x'{$php_code}'` tells mysql to expect a hex string.

This means the string is stored as a string in the DB, and is fully searchable.  But, since all chars are encoded as hex during the `INSERT` the special chars won't cause a problem.

Documentation:

[bin2hex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php)

[Mysql Hex Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/hexadecimal-values.html)