# Disallow characters in text field

Tags: php, security, special-characters

Should I disallow characters like ",',>,<,\ ... to be typed in an upload forms text field? The text will be send through PHP to a blog.

I heared that some characters might cause trouble and could be used to "hack / harm" servers. Which characters should be restricted?

Thanks for your input.
Michael

Comment: Don't blacklist characters. Whitelist them.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitelist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to restrict anything. The problem is that you have to *sanitize* all user input; for this specific type of data (possible HTML) it is necessary and enough to use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) on all user-provided data before displaying it as part of your page.

For example, if your form has a textarea named `post-body`, you should receive the user input (e.g. with `$_REQUEST['post-body']`) and save it to your database as-is (**warning:** use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to protect yourself from SQL injection at this stage!). When the time comes to display it, you would retrieve it from the database and print it with something like

```
echo htmlspecialchars($postBody);
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php) for some more background on data sanitization.

Answer (score 0):

Users data should be sanitized by [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function each time when you output users data, to avoid [XSS-attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSS).

Also, to work with users data in sql-queries, use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and prepared statements or [`mysql_real_escape_string`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function to avoid [SQL-injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198104/reference-what-is-a-perfect-code-sample-using-the-mysql-extension/6198584#6198584).

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?    $string = str_replace("\\\"", "\"", $string);
        $string = htmlspecialchars($string);
        $string = preg_replace( "/\r\n|\n|\r/", "<br>", $string );   ?>

<input type = "text" name = "string" id = "string" value = "<?=$string?>">
```