# Running a query while within a mysql_fetch_object while loop causing error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm runing a query to pull some movie data from a source table to import into a new database structure.  I'm then looping through the results using mysql_fetch_object and parsing data, calling external functions, etc to add the genres,actors,etc... to other tables in the database.

In one of my functions that I'm calling makes a query to a different table within the same database.  I'm then getting a "not a valid MySQL-Link resource" on that query.

Is there anything that would cause issues doing this?

Here's some code on how the error is occuring:

```
function doThis($thing) { 
   mysql_query("SELECT derp FROM herp WHERE sherp = $thing",$db)or die(mysql_error()); 
}

$query = mysql_query("SELECT foo FROM bar",$db);
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
   doThis($row->awesome);
}
```

This is essentially what I'm doing and I'm getting an error and don't know why.

Something of note may be that I'm connecting to 2 databases during this process.  The database I'm pulling data from and the database I'm importing into.

Thanks!

Comment: Your code example is a little off.. You don't call `function doThis($row->awesome);` but just `doThis($row->awesome);`.

Comment: You are not doing any error checking on your query - it could crash due to an error in your SQL, but you would never see it. See [Reference: What is a perfect code sample using the mysql extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6198104) for examples how to show errors

Comment: @Richards.  Thanks for the catch.  The function calls fine... but the error is on the query.  I've also added the "or die(mysql_error()) to the query.  Let me edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things: you haven't declared $db as a global variable within your function (so it's undeclared, causing the error you're seeing).  Add the following:

```
global $db;
```

Second, remove the function keyword from inside your while loop.  That's likely to cause php to biff.

Comment: the connection string is at the top of the page and referencing the variable $db.

Comment: Doesn't matter, the function cannot access default scoped variables, you have to global it for a function (outside of a class) to access a variable.

Comment: good call.  this worked beautifully. I've never had to do that before, but I suppose I've never had to build an import this large and complex, doing what it is doing. thanks for the help.