# mysql_query does not work

Tags: php, mysql, html

Can someone help me figure out why this code isn't working.

I am connected to the DB.
This snippet is within php tags.

```
$result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO attendeeser (firstName, lastName, shirtSize, title, organization, emailAddress, q1, q2, q3, refId)
             VALUES ('$_POST[firstName]', '$_POST[lastName]', '$_POST[shirtSize]', '$_POST[title]', '$_POST[organization]', '$_POST[emailAddress]', '$_POST[q1]', '$_POST[q2]', '$_POST[q3]', 'NULL')");
```

---

I figured it out. I didn't have q3 as a field in the table.

Comment: Please define "isn't working."

Comment: What George Cummins says. Also: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: have you checked generated query string or mysql error message? 'NULL' ?

Comment: Please always explain what exactly isn't working and what errors you get. Otherwise, everything people can do is guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

execute this

```
if(!mysql_query("INSERT INTO attendeeser (firstName, lastName, shirtSize, title, organization, emailAddress, q1, q2, q3, refId)
             VALUES ('$_POST[firstName]', '$_POST[lastName]', '$_POST[shirtSize]', '$_POST[title]', '$_POST[organization]', '$_POST[emailAddress]', '$_POST[q1]', '$_POST[q2]', '$_POST[q3]', 'NULL')")){
echo mysql_error();
}
```

that will display the error generated by mysql.

Comment: didn't have q3 as a field in the table. Facepalm.

Comment: @user821843: If this answer helped you solve your problem, you can upvote it and mark it as accepted by clicking the checkbox beside it. This will reward Pheonix for his work on your behalf, and will help future users of the site find solutions to their own problems.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, someone probably entered a quote or something.  DO NOT INSERT THIS WAY, you are wide open to SQL injection attacks.

Use PDO, or `mysql_real_escape_string()` at a minimum.

Comment: could you suggest a better way?

Comment: @user821843, I suggested two ways already.  Use PDO.  http://www.kitebird.com/articles/php-pdo.html

Comment: @user see here for a full example of Brad's first suggestion: [Reference: What is a perfect code sample using the mysql extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6198104)