# What is the error in my code that I get mysql_fetch_array warning?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display some data from mySQL, the db details are correct but I get this.

*Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource*

What is the error with my code below?

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost"," "," ");
mysql_select_db(" ", $con);
mysql_query('set names utf8');

$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '13' LIMIT 1";
$row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
echo $row['name'];

?>
```

**UPDATE**

I found my error it was a typo. This is what you get if you still use notepad...

Comment: Sheesh. Downvoting spree... Would the anonymous coward who hates all the correct answers please step forward and explain themselves?

Comment: Don't need 50 me too answers saying the exact same thing

Comment: @Greg: Note the timestamps on the answers. They were all done at pretty much the same time. You don't get notified by SO immediately when an answer is posted.

Comment: ... and no matter what, it's not good form to downvote correct answers @Greg. If you see a pile of "me too" answers, just leave them alone (or leave an acidic comment)

Comment: What does acidic mean in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$query` will be `FALSE` because the query you have entered is not valid; the return from `mysql_query` is `FALSE` when there was some error compiling or executing the query.

Change `LIMT` to `LIMIT` and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong spelling...

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '13' LIMT 1";
```

should be

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '13' LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got an error somewhere. Try:

```
$con = mysql_connect(...) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db(...) or die(mysql_error());

$res = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo, LIMT -> LIMIT

Answer (score 1):

Use error handling to get information about errors. The message will tell you that you have a syntax error (`LIMT` instead of `LIMIT`).

A minimal example:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '13' LIMT 1";

if (!$query) trigger_error("mySQL Error: ".mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
```

The use of `trigger_error()` instead of `die()` is so you can avoid the message getting shown on a live site. Other than that, `die()` is also fine.

See also [Reference: What is a perfect code sample using the mysql extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198104/reference-what-is-a-perfect-code-sample-using-the-mysql-extension)

Comment: Thank you for the reference, it will help me as a beginner to write better code.

Answer (score 0):

Simple typo: `LIMT` should be `LIMIT`