# "Access denied" error talking to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting this warning on line 25:

> Warning :
> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' >(using password: NO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\shadaab\register.php on line 25
>
> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in C:\xampp\htdocs\shadaab\register.php on line 25
> Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

I have following SQL query on line 25:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT email FROM user WHERE email='$email'")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: How are you connecting to the mySQL database? Are you connecting at all?

Comment: Possibly helpful: [Reference: What is a perfect code sample using the mysql extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6198104)

Comment: the problem is with the mysql_connect . check the parameters are right.

Comment: @Aditii Was this caused by the same issue as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136269/getting-access-denied-error-when-executing-mysql-query-in-php/7136292#7136292) that I helped you with earlier? If so, you may want to flag this post for moderator attention (see the "flag" link below your question) and ask them to merge this question with that one.

Answer (score 1):

The error message means:

- You have not connected to database (using `mysql_connect` and `mysql_select_db`)
- If you have specified `mysql_connect`, you are not specifying correct username and password to the `mysql_connect` function.

Here is how you can connect to your db **before** running your SQL queries:

```
$con = mysql_connect('server address', 'username', 'password') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('your db name') or die(mysql_error());
```

---

[More information on official documentation.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

Comment: $localhost="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $dbname="shadaab";
    $con=mysql_connect("$localhost","$username","$password");
    mysql_select_db("$dbname",$con);

Comment: append `or die(mysql_error())` to those function like i have shown to see if there is an error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you provide invalid data in mysql_connect. Check user/password.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a connection problem, check that you are calling `mysql_connect` above that line, and that your settings (password, host name, database name) and permissions are correct. [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)