# php form issue with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

I am trying to write a little project management webapps as a newby - I do appologise for this but I could not find any near...

So I have x type of project which can be select and load through AJAX.

Every type has at least 2-3 steps to complete them so I need more php pages.

I have spent lots of time to figure it out but it is time to ask someone who knows the answer.

Question: When User presses the Submit button I need to check if all the input box are correct and then save to a SQL table and then move to the next page if any of these would fail I have to stop.

code:

```
<form id="pdf" method="post">
New project name:<input type="text" name="pr-name" placeholder="new project name..."><br/>
New project end date:<input type="text" name="pr-end" placeholder="date..."><br/>

<textarea class="ckeditor" name="pagecontent"  id="pagecontent"></textarea>

<?php
    include_once "ckeditor/ckeditor.php";
    $CKEditor = new CKEditor();
    $CKEditor->basePath = 'ckeditor/';

   // Set global configuration (will be used by all instances of CKEditor).
   $CKEditor->config['width'] = 600;   
    // Change default textarea attributes
   $CKEditor->textareaAttributes = array(“cols” => 80, “rows” => 10);

   $CKEditor->replace("pagecontent");


$sbmt_caption = "continue ->";
if ($_POST["submit_name"]==$sbmt_caption)
{ 
  $prname = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST["pr-name"]);
  $prend = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST["pr-end"]);
  $prmenu = "pdf";
  $prcontent = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST["pagecontent"]);
  $sql = "INSERT INTO projects (pr-name,enddate, sel, content) VALUES('$prname','$prend', '$prmenu', '$prcontent')";

  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  if (!$result){
  echo mysql_error();
  }
}
?>
```

"/>

this code with the mysql_query bit even doesn't work for me some reason.

Could anyone give me some hint?

Comment: Use `mysql_error()` to get an error message from mySQL. Possibly helpful: [Reference: What is a perfect code sample using the mysql extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6198104)

Comment: You should not use "-" for field names because the "-" sign has a mathematical function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four tips:

1. Check if your query success and ouput errors if any with

   ```
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
   if (!$result){
        echo mysql_error();
   }
   ```
2. Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) instead of direct embedding parameters into a query string

   ```
   $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO projects (pr-name,enddate, sel, content) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
   $stmt->execute(array($prname,$prend, $prmenu, $prcontent))
   ```
3. Use `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST`. `$_REQUEST` array is build up from cookie,get,post and session according to `variables_order` php.ini directive, so you may just get your values overwritten.
4. your submit button is not posted at all. So add `name` attribute to it and check it in your if statement. Also, don't use just plain string `continue ->`. Store it in the variable and use it.

   ```
   $sbmt_caption = "continue ->";
   if ($_POST["submit_name"]==$sbmt_caption){
       //your processing here
   }

   <input id="submitButton" name="submit_name" type="submit" value="<?php echo $sbmt_caption?>"/>
   ```

Comment: Thanks John, this is great. I am getting closer to the solution. I have changed and now I am having an SQL error message which is good! So all the data went into the right place however this is the message You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-name,enddate, sel, content) VALUES('etwtr','2011-09-30', 'pdf', '

\r\n dfhftd' at line 1  Can you have a look at it?

Comment: I have done 1, 3, 4 from your list. I don't understand No 2. but I am willing to learn:)

Comment: I think you have to escape `pr-name` column name with backticks: `INSERT INTO projects (\`pr-name\`,enddate, sel, content) VALUES(?,?,?,?)`

Comment: As of number 2, [`PHP:PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) is a PHP's database abstraction layer, that provides generalized access to almost every modern DB used with PHP, including MySQL. It supports object-oriented style. The prepared statements itself is a DB feature that allows executing multiple similar queries with single planning phase, thus increasing performance. Also, PHP DB drivers automatically performs any escaping/type-coersion, so it is considered more secure and robust. There are a lot of questions about prepared statements on SO, try searching for it.

Comment: thanks John, I have changed in the TABLE as I will use it a lot.:) AND IT IS WORKING NOW!!!!!! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the submit-button a "name" and check the existency of that name in your second code on line 2, not the "value".

Comment: thanks for the comment, I have given a name but what shall I check here if($_REQUEST["submit"] == "continue ->")
could you give me a hint please?

Comment: Use e.g. if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {}.
See also php.net/isset. Please also have a look at J0HN's answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First u should have a client side validation code in javascript to validate the inputs entered by the client is valid or not and u can stop him without sending a request to the server. This reduces the waiting time of the user.

Comment: I try to do some and be back with the result. Thanks for the hint.