# \ being added when uploading a link to db via form

Tags: php, mysql, html

Hope you can help me with this. On one of the fields in my add product page, I have the advertisers link to his product. It basically is a link and a button direct the customer to that link.

This is what I uploaded in the field:

```
<a target='_blank' href='http://click.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/click?id=3qM*AG8K6Qo&offerid=146141.3706263&type=2&subid=0'><img border="0" src='style/buynowbutton.png' width='138' height='20'><a/>
```

and this is what ends up in the db:

```
<a target=\'_blank\' href=\'http://click.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/click?id=3qM*AG8K6Qo&offerid=146141.3706263&type=2&subid=0\'><img border=\"0\" src=\'style/buynowbutton.png\' width=\'138\' height=\'20\'><a/>
```

How can I stop this from happening?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Because this strings automatically [escaped](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc)
[Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198104/reference-what-is-a-perfect-code-sample-using-the-mysql-extension), how you can improve your work with DB.

Use [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) and [htmlspecialchars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) when output:

```
print htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($text));
```