# Warning: mysql_fetch_array():

Tags: php

Is it possible  to rewrite this script part it in different way? Because it works  fine in my localhost ,but  when i moved it in hosting it shows:

> ```
> Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /***************************.php on line 67
> ```

```
<? 
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tableName"; 
//////Below error line
$total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query)); 
/////////////
$total_pages = $total_pages['num'];
?>
```

Comment: Check your database connection. Is MySQL running? Have you put the right database credentials for the connection?

Comment: Do some basic error checking. `mysql_query()` probably fails for some reason. `mysql_error()` can tell you why.

Comment: Please please read at least a few dozen of the related links (on the right of this page). This error is reported again and again and again...

Comment: [Please look around to see if your question has been asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/search).

Answer (score -1):

You can do just:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $tableName";

$total_pages = mysql_result(mysql_query($query), 0);
```

See [PHP: mysql_result()](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-result.php).

Comment: This is no better than the original code - when `mysql_query()` fails, it will return `false`. It is standard practice to catch that possibility, and if it occurs, to throw an error or exception containing `mysql_error()`'s output. The way you show will break exactly like the OP's original code, with the same error message. See also: [Reference: What is a perfect code sample using the mysql extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6198104)