# Android php mysql query

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I get a string from java: "2011-11-25 08:16:50"
post_date column is TIMESTAMP
But the following query gives no results. What is the error?

```
$date2 = $_POST['Date'];

$result= mysql_query("Select * FROM (Select * FROM user WHERE latitude > $minLat AND latitude < $maxLat AND longitude > $minLon AND longitude < $maxLon AND post_date > $date2 ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT $amount1) a ORDER BY post_id");

while($results = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    $output[]=$results;

print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
```

Comment: Can you clarify whether there is no output at all, or an empty JSON array? Either way, you are not doing any error checking. You *need* to do that after a `mysql_query()` call. Otherwise, your script will break if the query fails. How to do this is outlined in the [manual on `mysql_query()`](http://php.net/mysql_query) or in this [reference question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198104/reference-what-is-a-perfect-code-sample-using-the-mysql-extension)

Comment: Also, the code you show is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Use the proper sanitation method of your library (like `mysql_real_escape_string()` for the classic mysql library), or switch to PDO and prepared statements.

Comment: please edit the query to 

$result= mysql_query("Select * FROM (Select * FROM user WHERE latitude > $minLat AND latitude < $maxLat AND longitude > $minLon AND longitude < $maxLon AND post_date > $date2 ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT $amount1) a ORDER BY post_id") or die(mysql_error());
and give us the error I think this is a syntex error with mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must single-quote dates in MySQL.  Additionally, since you are acquiring it directly from `$_POST`, you are advised to escape it with `mysql_real_escape_string()` first.

```
$result= mysql_query("
  Select * FROM (
    Select * FROM user 
    WHERE
      latitude > $minLat 
      AND latitude < $maxLat 
      AND longitude > $minLon 
      AND longitude < $maxLon 

      -- Surround $date2 with quotes
      AND post_date > '$date2'
    ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT $amount1) a
  ORDER BY post_id");
```

Comment: duh...thanks a lot guys it was the quote...anyway..yes I know for the sql injection thanks again.