# MySQL - I have two query but one doesn't work, and one does. Help me please?

Tags: php, mysql

```
if ($_GET['action'] == "like")
{
mysql_query("UPDATE blog SET like=like+1 WHERE id=".$_GET['id']."");
header('Location: blog.php?id='.$_GET['id'].'');
}
else if ($_GET['action'] == "dislike")
{
mysql_query("UPDATE blog SET dislike = dislike+1 WHERE id = ".$_GET['id']."");
header('Location: blog.php?id='.$_GET['id'].'');
}
```

The "dislike" action works great! But the "like" one doesn't. It's close to be the same thing?

Can someone help me???

Comment: What's the sense of this   .""   after your query?

Comment: add basic error checking with mysql_error()

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are not doing any error checking in your queries, so it's no wonder you're unable to see what happens when a query fails. How to show errors properly is outlined in the [manual on `mysql_query()`](http://php.net/mysql_query) or in this [reference question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198104/reference-what-is-a-perfect-code-sample-using-the-mysql-extension)

Comment: Also, the code you show is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Use the proper sanitation method of your library (like `mysql_real_escape_string()` for the classic mysql library), or switch to PDO and prepared statements.

Comment: I hope that you do realize that accepting user input without escaping it for MySQL poses a severe security risk... But on topic: what does MySQL say if you paste the query in (e.g.) phpmyadmin (or echo `mysql_error()` like @Dagon suggests)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LIKE is a keyword. Use backticks :

```
UPDATE blog SET `like`=`like`+1 ...
```

In general, it's much better not to name column after keywords (`LIKE,CASE,SELECT,WHERE`, etc).

Example

```
mysql_query("UPDATE blog SET `like`=`like`+1 WHERE id='".
       mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])."'");
```

Or if your id is integer, you can do in this particular case just `.... WHERE id=".(int)$_GET['id']`

Comment: Definitely take care to backtick like advised here. It doesn't hurt to know the basic reserved terms for mysql.

Comment: Thank you a1ex07!!! I'll try! But own I can use "mysql_real_escape_string()" ?? It's my first PHP and MySQL website..

Comment: @Frederick Marcoux  : Added example with mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: @a1ex07 It doesn't work... -__-' But can you help me with "mysql_real_escape_string()" ?

Comment: if ($_GET['action'] == "like")
{
mysql_query("UPDATE blog SET 'like'='like'+1 WHERE id=".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])."");
header('Location: blog.php?id='.$_GET['id'].'');
}

And it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using backtick character for like ? It's not a single quote.

Answer (score 1):

A good plan would be to check the return value from mysql_error() to get the actual error from MySQL (You can check this by simply echo'ing mysql_error()).

Other than that you really want to throw in an exit() after the call to header() to actually terminate the execution of the script right there, and you also want to add mysql_real_escape_string to escape the GET-arguments you're passing in to MySQL. You do not want to use user supplied data like that unescaped or unfiltered.

Comment: All true and good points, but `mysql_real_escape_string` would not protect from vulnerability in this specific case. Look closely

Comment: It's from a link and the user doesn't see the URL, I redirect between two pages...

Comment: @Frederick you still need to escape the SQL. It's trivial to see the URL for anybody with a little bit of technical knowledge