# mysql php error - quote system

Tags: php, mysql

I can't get my authors from my php quotes

i have a quotes table:
id, quote, aid

i have a author table:
id, name, etc...

```
<?php

$DB_SERVER = "localhost";
$DB_USER = "root";
$DB_PASS = "";
$DB_NAME = "test";
$con = mysql_connect($DB_SERVER, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);
mysql_select_db($DB_NAME);

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quotes WHERE id = ".$_GET['id'], $con);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($sql);

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM author where aid = " . $row[1], $con);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($sql); 


var_dump($row);
```

now i get this error
Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/domain.com/php.php on line 14
NULL

Comment: You are not doing any error checking in your query. You *need* to do that after a `mysql_query()` call. Otherwise, your script will break if the query fails. How to do this is outlined in the [manual on `mysql_query()`](http://php.net/mysql_query) or in this [reference question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198104/reference-what-is-a-perfect-code-sample-using-the-mysql-extension)

Comment: Also, the code you show is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Use the proper sanitation method of your library (like `mysql_real_escape_string()` for the classic mysql library), or switch to PDO and prepared statements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you `print_r($row);` after the first query you will see something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => id
    [1] => quote 
    [2] => aid
)
```

then on your second query you use `$row[1]` which is the quote (string) and not the number.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM author where aid = " . $row[1], $con);
```

if you echo the error (using `mysql_error($con)`) you will see something:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'a quote

instead of using `mysql_fetch_row` use `mysql_fetch_assoc` and the key of the array will be the name of the column. This way, it's very easy to retrieve data. And don't forget to close your connection.

```
<?php
$_GET['id'] = 1;
$DB_SERVER = "localhost";
$DB_USER = "root";
$DB_PASS = "";
$DB_NAME = "test";
$con = mysql_connect($DB_SERVER, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);
mysql_select_db($DB_NAME);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quotes WHERE id = " . (int)$_GET['id'], $con); // or you can use the mysql_real_escape_string
if(!$sql) {
  echo mysql_error($con);
}
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
mysql_free_result($sql);

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM author where id = " . (int)$row['aid'], $con);
if(!$sql) {
  echo mysql_error($con);
}
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql); 
mysql_free_result($sql);

print_r($row);
mysql_close($con);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.
>
> mysql_query() will also fail and return FALSE if the user does not
> have permission to access the table(s) referenced by the query.

So just do some quick error checking

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM author where aid = " . $row[1], $con);
if ( $sql ) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($sql); 
}
else {
    //error
}
```

Comment: +1. You can call `mysql_error($con)` to get the specific MySQL error.