# What is the best way to count number of rows without returning resource (10, mysql result)?

Tags: mysql, count

The users table that I have contains 0 users, with rows userid, firstname and lastname. When I execute this query, I get: (10, mysql result). Shouldn't this return boolean false since there are no users in the table?

```
$count = mysql_query("SELECT userid FROM users WHERE userid = '$userid' AND trash = '0' ORDER BY DATETIME DESC");

var_dump($count);
```

I'm just trying to find the count of total users in the table.

Comment: Side note: You are not doing any error checking in your query. You *need* to do that after a `mysql_query()` call. Otherwise, your script will break if the query fails. How to do this is outlined in the [manual on `mysql_query()`](http://php.net/mysql_query) or in this [reference question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198104/reference-what-is-a-perfect-code-sample-using-the-mysql-extension)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysql_query returns a [resource](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php), not an array. You should use the [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) function for this.