# mysqli fetch_object() throwing an error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Os i'm starting to use mysqli, i'm getting a little confused with how it works.

So i have a function:

```
function verify_payment_date()
{
    $today = date("Y-m-d");

    $email = $_SESSION['email'];

    $result = $this->conn->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email=$email");

    while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        $next_payment_date = $row['next_payment_date'];
    }
}
```

To set up my connect i do this in the same class:

```
 private $conn;

function __construct() 
{
    $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or 
                  die('There was a problem connecting to the database.');
}
```

can anyone give me a helping hand here because i'm totally lost. I was basing some of the code on this website:
http://www.willfitch.com/mysqli-tutorial.html

Also the error i'm getting is:

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in /home/vhosts/tradingeliteclub.com/subdomains/test/httpdocs/FES/members/classes/Mysql.php on line 52

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are not doing any error checking in your query, so it's no wonder your code breaks when it fails. Do proper checking after each `mysql_query()` call. Otherwise, your script will break if the query fails. How to do this is outlined in the [manual on `mysql_query()`](http://php.net/mysql_query) or in this [reference question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198104/reference-what-is-a-perfect-code-sample-using-the-mysql-extension)

Comment: Put the email address in quotes: `$this->conn->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email'");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$result` is not mysql result, your query failed. Try

```
$result = $this->conn->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email'");
// apostrophes
```

instead.

`$this->conn->query` returns `resource` on success, `false` on fail. You can avoid the error this way

```
if($result) while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
    $next_payment_date = $row['next_payment_date'];
}
```