# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object

Tags: php, expressionengine, freeform

I am working with MySQL in conjunction with ExpressionEngine 2.2.1. This version of ExpressionEngine automatically comes with a Query Module, which I am using to filter and display entry results from a module called Freeform. I am using Freeform version 3.1.1. All of these elements are working well together and displaying the desired results on my local setup. However when I push my code to production, I am receiving this error:

**Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxx.com/systemxxx/expressionengine/modules/query/mod.query.php on line 183**

Here is this section of the code beginning on line 183 of mod.query.php (I did not code this php, nor have I ever coded php, this was already included with the site that I am working on.):

```
183          if ($query->num_rows() == 0)
184          {
185          return $this->return_data = $this->EE->TMPL->no_results();
186          }
```

Here is how I am using the Query Module in my HTML Template:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT first_name, last_name, email, city FROM exp_freeform_entries WHERE city = 'New York'"}
    <tr>
        <td>{first_name}</td>
        <td>{last_name}</td>
        <td>{email}</td>
        <td>{city}</td>
    </tr>
{/exp:query}
```

Does anyone know why this error is occurring? Why would it be occurring on production but not locally?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are probably not doing any error checking in your query. You need to check whether the  `mysql_query()` call actually succeeded. Otherwise, your script will break if the query fails. How to do this is outlined in the manual on `mysql_query()` or in [this reference question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198104/reference-what-is-a-perfect-code-sample-using-the-mysql-extension)

Comment: probably you missing uploading some files on production check

Comment: Thanks Hemant, but all files are uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to make sure the database in Production has the same structure as your Local environment.

Perform the following steps from phpMyAdmin or your favorite MySQL GUI client:

1. Select your ExpressionEngine database
2. Execute the following SQL Statements:
3. `DESCRIBE exp_freeform_fields;`
4. `SELECT name FROM exp_freeform_fields;`

Compare the results from your Local MySQL Database to your Production MySQL Database.

Answer (score 0):

You probably got different database content on production and local systems so the statement fails on the production system producing an error.

You should try executing the statement in phpmyadmin or something like that to see if your sql statement is error-free and doesn't have any conflicts with naming.

Comment: How can I try executing my statement to see if it is error free? Actually diving into phpmyadmin is the part of our site that I am still very vague on.

Comment: Look around phpmyadmin, there's a possibility to execute raw SQL, just paste your statement there.

Comment: Ans yes, if your database is missing some fields on your production server that's most likely causing this issue and you will need to create them. Maybe the best solution for that would be to give the control panel another try.

Comment: Cool, I found where to execute the raw SQL. I pasted my statement and it actually returned results. The webpage is still not working in a browser though...

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your $query object has no valid connection. Control your username, password and database configuration.

Comment: Could you explain this further? As far as I know, my username, password, & database configuration is all correct

Answer (score 0):

Enable debugging in your `config.php` and `database.php` to see detailed error messages:

**/system/expressionengine/config/config.php**

```
$config['debug'] = '1';
```

**/system/expressionengine/config/database.php**

```
$db['expressionengine']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
```

It also wouldn't hurt to:

- Verify your MySQL database credentials
- Check Apache's and/or PHP's `error_log`

Hopefully, these steps will allow you to get more insight into your problem.