# mysql_num_rows() gives a BOOL value

Tags: php, mysql, warnings, mysql-num-rows

I have this query in  my PHP:

```
<?php
$comments_list = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY `date` DESC, `time` DESC LIMIT 5");
echo mysql_error();
if (mysql_num_rows($comments_list) != 0)
{
    echo('<ul>');
    while ($comment = mysql_fetch_array($comments_list))
    {
        echo('<li>'.substr($comment['content'],0,70).'</li>');
    }
    echo('</ul>');
}
else
{
    echo('<center>No comment.</center>');
}
?>
```

And it gives this error if my table is empty:

`Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\admin\index.php on line 101`

**EDIT: I was querying `LIMIT 5` before the `ORDER BY`. Now it's fixed and I added the `echo mysql_error()` as edited in the question.**

Comment: -1 for not reading the documentation. http://php.net/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: As to fixing your SQL query, put the LIMIT clause __after__ the ORDER BY clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `$comments_list` is `false`, use `mysql_error()` to see what is wrong.

```
$comments_list = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments LIMIT 5 ORDER BY `date` DESC, `time` DESC");
if (!$comments_list ) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not doing any error checking in your query. You *need* to do that after a `mysql_query()` call, because on a query error, [it will return boolean `false`](http://php.net/mysql_query) and your script will break exactly the way you show.

Add error checking to your query. How to do this is outlined in the [manual on `mysql_query()`](http://php.net/mysql_query) or in this [reference question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198104/reference-what-is-a-perfect-code-sample-using-the-mysql-extension)