# "mysql_fetch_assoc()" error when data in mysql field is changed

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mySQL database from where I fetch some data via PHP.

This is what I've got:

```
if ($db_found) {

    $URL_ID = $_GET["a"];

    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM tb_employees WHERE URL_ID = $URL_ID";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);

    while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $firstname = $db_field['firstname'];
        $surname = $db_field['surname'];
        $function = $db_field['function'];
        $email = $db_field['email'];
        $telnr = $db_field['telnr'];
    }

    mysql_close($db_handle);
}
else {
    print "Database not found... please try again later.";
    mysql_close($db_handle);
}
```

The URL_ID field in my mySQL database is, for this example, 001. When I go to www.mydomain.com/index.php?a=001 it fetches all the data, puts it into a variable, and I can echo the variables without any problem.

Now, I want to change the URL_ID, and I've changed it to "62ac1175" in the mySQL database. However, when I proceed to www.mydomain.com/index.php?a=62ac1175, I get this error message:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in
>   mydomain.com\db_connect.php on line 17

The field in mySQL has varchar(8) as type and utf8_general_ci as collation.

If I change the entry back to 001 and change my URL to ?a=001, it works fine again.

What's going wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing any error checking in your query, so it's no wonder it breaks if the query fails. How to add proper error checking is outlined in the [manual on `mysql_query()`](http://php.net/mysql_query) or in this [reference question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198104/reference-what-is-a-perfect-code-sample-using-the-mysql-extension)

Example:

```
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

if (!$result)
 { trigger_error("mySQL error: ".mysql_error());
   die(); }
```

your  query is breaking because you aren't wrapping the input in quotes. You can avoid* quotes only for integers (which `62ac1175` is not). Try

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM tb_employees WHERE URL_ID = '$URL_ID'";
```

Also, the code you show is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Use the proper sanitation method of your library (like `mysql_real_escape_string()` for the classic mysql library that you are using), or switch to PDO and prepared statements.

In your code, this would look like so: Instead of

```
$URL_ID = $_GET["a"];
```

do

```
$URL_ID = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["a"]);
```

<sub>* however, if you avoid quotes, `mysql_real_escape_string()` won't work and you need to check manually whether the parameter actually is an integer.</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers and explanation. The answer was simple as that, indeed.