# MySQL Display Multiple Rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have somewhat of a problem, using the following code:

```
$getTS = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM book WHERE chapter='$url' && verse='$verse'");
```

When I use

```
mysql_num_rows($getTS)
```

it returns 2, 3, etc (which is perfect), however, when I am printing it out I only one get row using the following code:

```
$rowTS = mysql_fetch_array($getTS);
$summary = $rowTS['text'];
echo $summary;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to do this in a loop

```
while($rowTS = mysql_fetch_array($getTS)) { 
   $summary = $rowTS['text']; 
   echo $summary; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need iterate loop when you are using [mysql_fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

From documentation

> Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the
>   internal data pointer ahead.

```
$getTS = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM book WHERE chapter='$url' && verse='$verse'");      

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getTS , MYSQL_NUM)) {
       $summary = $row['text']; 
       echo $summary;
}
```

Comment: This does not work. If you fetch with numerical indexes, you can't access them by string keys.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by using a so called iterator. The old `mysql_*` functions do not provide it, but it can be easily written (or re-used, see this earlier answer: [PHP file cannot enter some part of code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11580420/367456)):

```
$getTS = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM book WHERE chapter='$url' && verse='$verse'");
$rows  = new MySqlResult($getTS);
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    $summary = $row['text'];
    echo $summary;
}
```

You can further improve it by using a database object directly, e.g. for the query:

```
$db    = new MySql();
...
$rows  = $db->query("SELECT * FROM book WHERE chapter='$url' && verse='$verse'");
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    $summary = $row['text'];
    echo $summary;
}
```

The next step then would be probably that you use PDO because `mysql_*` is deprecated and PDO comes with such kind of a functionality out of the box.