# Display a Bar Chart using Google Chart API in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, google-api, google-visualization

I have been searching a lot for this. I got the solution. And here it is. It is been done using AJAX in php.
I have 2 pages on is googleapi.php and other getData.php that is been used by AJAX request sent from googleapi.php.

**googleapi.php**

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the Ajax API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    //google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart(object) {

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(object);
      var options = {
           title: 'Test API',
          is3D: 'true',
          width: 200,
          height: 100
        };
      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      // Do not forget to check your div ID
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    function show()
    {

        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata.php?name=jaspreet",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = getResponse;
    }
    function getResponse()
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4){
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            var obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            drawChart(obj);
        }
    }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--this is the div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
    <select id="name" onchange="show();">
        <option value="test">test</option>
        <option value="test1">test1</option>
        <option value="test2">test2</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

**getData.php**

```
<?php $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Failed to connect with database!!!!");
mysql_select_db("student", $con); 
// The Chart table contains two fields: weekly_task and percentage
// This example will display a pie chart. If you need other charts such as a Bar chart, you will need to modify the code a little to make it work with bar chart and other charts
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM marks where name='jas'");

/*
---------------------------
example data: Table (Chart)
--------------------------
marks     percentage
English           30
Maths             40
Science            44
*/

$rows = array();
//flag is not needed
$flag = true;
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(

    // Labels for your chart, these represent the column titles
    // Note that one column is in "string" format and another one is in "number" format as pie chart only required "numbers" for calculating percentage and string will be used for column title
    array('label' => 'subject', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'marks', 'type' => 'number')

);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $temp = array();
    // the following line will be used to slice the Pie chart
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['subject']); 

    // Values of each slice
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['marks']); 
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
echo $jsonTable;
?>
```

That is all, You need to create a database. It works like a charm.

Comment: It's not question. Its a solution. I have been searching a lot for this. Got this worked after getting the help from stackoverflow. So I thought of posting my working code for others.

Comment: @Daan I believe JassJava is not asking a question, but rather displaying the solution they found to a problem. If that is the case, it might have been better to make the original post in the form of a question and then post their solution as an answer. See [this link](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) for more details.

Comment: Thank You. I really appreciate. I will take care of this.

Answer (score 1):

I know that your post was an "answer" but I figured I would chime in. If you are looking to dynamically enter data into a Google chart you can simply echo out into the javascript using PHP . The php can be used to get information from your server or mysql table.

Here is an example:

```
    <?php   $i = 0; $grab = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `productList` WHERE 1");
    $pricelist = mysql_fetch_array($grab);
    $numberofproducts = mysql_num_rows($grab);

                              ?>       
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['parts', 'Prices'],
      ['Number of Products',  <?php echo $numberofproducts;?>],

    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Number of Products',
      hAxis: {title: '', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}},
                width: 980,
                height: 200
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```