# mySQL entries not updating

Tags: php, mysql

Not sure what is causing this, but I have two ints, like and dislike.
They're updated by the mysql query:

```
    if ($like == "like"){
    mysql_query("UPDATE updates set like = like + 1 WHERE id='$id'");
    echo $like;
} else if ($like == "dislike") {
    mysql_query("UPDATE updates set dislike = dislike + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    echo $like;
}
```

The echo comes out, but, the actual query does not update the value. I'm baffled as to why this happens. Any reason as to why this happens? Thanks, Chris

Comment: You are not doing any error checking in your queries so it's no wonder they break silently. See e.g. this reference question for how to do a proper mySQL query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198104

Comment: I would recommend that you assign the query to a variable and echo that out as your debug. This will give you insight as to what SQL you are running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because `like` is a reserved word in most SQL dialects. You may need to put the `like` in double quotes.

Refer to this list of reserved words for MySQL:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 1):

You have not shown us where you set $id which is critical. I am assuming it's some form of GET or POST, but until I see I am unsure.

Comment: $id = $_GET['associd']; This is set from an AJAX request. When I echo ID, it appears correctly as well.