# Resource ID #6 when checking for existing data entry

Tags: php, mysql, database

we're trying to check if a token which has been generated earlier is available in our Database, however we're getting the Error code "Resource ID #6" when we try to extract a matching database entry from the database.

Here's a snippet of our code:

```
$key= $_GET['token'];
$keytest = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tokens WHERE token = '$key'");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you trying to echo the $keytest

Comment: `$keytest` is a resource returned by your `mysql_query()`, not an actual row object.

Comment: Yes

@Edvin Tenovimas Could you explain it a little bit further, please?

Comment: Yes, I could. Hold on.

Comment: Just take a look at any basic tutorial on PHP and mysql - and STOP using PHP's deprecated mysql_ API

Comment: Hi. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this, though.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, you should not be using `mysql_*` extension because it is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). You're also vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) because you're not escaping your inputs.

Regarding about `Resource id #4`, *it is a resource returned by your `mysql_query()` call, not an actual row object/array* ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9618642/3884852)).

If you want to get an object/array, you need to add an additional line:

```
$keytest = mysql_fetch_array($keytest);
```

Now your `$keytest` is an object/array (array more likely). To get value from this array, you need to specify array's key. For example, if you have a column called `unique_id`, then you can `echo` it by writing something like:

```
echo 'Token unique ID: '.$keytest['unique_id'];
```

That's it about how to retrieve data. But as I have said earlier, you should not use `mysql_*`, better is to use either [prepared statements](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) or [mysqli_*](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp).